# Program PHP Header to Float Logo when search field is present

Tags: php, header, logos

I'm reconfiguring a header for a Wordpress Theme.  I just want to do this simple function:

- Float the Logo to the center of the header when a search field is not present.

There used to be widgets in place where the search field is when a visitor navigates to a products page.  I'd like to instead remove the rule that was in place for the widgets and float the Logo center, unless there is a search box, then I'd like to keep the Logo at the left.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="logo" class="col-sm-3">
            <?php 
            $logourl = SNSSIMEN_THEME_URI.'/assets/img/logo.png';
            if ( snssimen_get_option('header_logo') && snssimen_get_option('header_logo','','url') !='' ){
                $logourl = snssimen_get_option('header_logo','','url');
            }
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo( 'sitename' )); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($logourl); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo( 'sitename' )); ?>"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right col-sm-9">
            <div class="header-right-inner">
                <div class="row">
                **<?php if ( $snssimen_topHeaderSidebar == 'header_sidebar'):?>
                    <?php if(is_active_sidebar('header_sidebar')) dynamic_sidebar('header_sidebar');?>**
                <?php else: // Header sidebar search box?>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div id="headerRightSearchForm">
                                <?php // Get Woocommerce categoies
                                $args = array(
                                    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                                    'orderby'       => 'name',
                                    'show_count'    => 0,
                                    'pad_counts'    => 0,
                                    'hierarchical'  => 0,
                                    'title_li'      => '',
                                    'hide_empty'    => 0
                                );
                                $all_categories = get_categories($args);
                                ?>
```

The coding in the asteriks is the coding for what was there, but is not there anymore.  Any suggestions?  Regards.

Comment: This problem can be simplified down to HTML and CSS. Perhaps updating your question with rendered HTML output would be useful as readers could then duplicate your problem.

Comment: This is not a php question, please replace your tags to html/css

Comment: hi @makaatman.  I have tried solving this with both HTML and CSS.  If you take look at my coding, the issue lies within the php tags.  I'm trying to create a rule the both integrates the logo and search field.  The search field only appears on product pages.  On other pages there used to be widgets that my client wanted removed.  If you could offer some suggestions that would be a big help.  Thank you.